# Why does console.log() execute immediately in a Promises's resolve() function?

Tags: javascript, promise

Take the following, for example:

```
function sayHello () {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Were inside the promise');

    return resolve(5);
  })
}

sayHello().then(function(success){
  console.log(success)
})

console.log('Im outside the promise')
```

We know that this executes, in this order:

```
Were inside the promise
Im outside the promise
5
```

And then, for something like:

```
function sayHello () {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Were inside the promise');

    return resolve((function(){
      return 5
    })());
  })
}

sayHello().then(function(success){
  console.log(success)
})

console.log('Im outside the promise')
```

It returns the same sequence of `console.log` output as the former example. Great, makes sense; whatever the value in resolve is, gets piped as an argument when `then()` executes.

Why however, when I have something like the below:

```
function sayHello () {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Were inside the promise');

    return resolve(console.log(5));
  })
}

sayHello().then(function(success){
  console.log(success)
})

console.log('Im outside the promise')
```

Do I get this order:

```
Were inside the promise
5
Im outside the promise
```

Comment: If your promise is used to make an asyncronus call, then the last console log could be called before your then function, but in this case, without an async call, your code will be called instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While resolver function is called in the next 'tick', its argument is evaluated immediately. That's why you see `console.log(5)` executed *before* `then` callback in your third snippet example. This becomes more clear if you change your second snippet into this:

```js
function sayHello() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Were inside the promise');
    return resolve((function() {
      console.log('Inside resolver argument');
      return 5
    })());
  })
}
sayHello().then(function(success) {
  console.log(success)
});
console.log('Im outside the promise');
```

Comment: Got it. This explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation of `Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) explains:

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `executor`
>
> > A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The executor function is executed immediately by the `Promise` implementation, passing `resolve` and `reject` functions (the `executor` is called before the `Promise` constructor even returns the created object). [...]
> >     The executor normally initiates some asynchronous work, and then, once that completes, either calls the `resolve` function to resolve the promise or else rejects it if an error occurred. [...]
> >     The return value of the executor is ignored.

Armed with the knowledge exposed above, your code should be something like:

```
function sayHello () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Start an asynchronous operation
    // This example uses setTimeout() to simulate a lengthy operation (1 second)
    // but in a real program you probably start a network request, 
    // a database operation or a file system operation
    setTimeout(function() {
        // This is when the async operation completes
        console.log('Were inside the promise');
        // Fulfill the promise, set '5' as the value returned by the promise
        resolve(5);
    }, 1000);
  });
}


sayHello().then(function(success){
  console.log(success);
});

console.log('Im outside the promise');
```